# R tkbutton won't resize

Tags: r

This has probably a simple answer but I don't know what else to try.
I have enclosed the problem, so I only provide a small piece of code. I am making a graphical interface using `tkltk`

These buttons are supposed to occupy all the horizontal space when I make the window bigger by dragging the corners with the mouse. The vertical size is supposed to stay the same.

I have been able to make it work for a single button (code below), but not with a row of buttons.

Thank you in advance

```
require(tcltk)

botos1 <- function(panel){panel}
panel01<- tktoplevel(bg="darkcyan")
row1 = tkframe(panel01,width = 500, height = 70, bg = "yellow",borderwidth = 3)

tkgrid(row1)
tkgrid.configure(row1,sticky="ew")
tkgrid.columnconfigure(panel01,0,weight=1)
tkgrid.rowconfigure(panel01,0,weight=1)
tkgrid.rowconfigure(row1,0,weight=1)
tkgrid.columnconfigure(row1,0,weight=1)
tkgrid.configure(row1,sticky='nwe') 


bot1<- tkbutton(row1,text="Time series",width = 35,command=botos1)

tkgrid(bot1)
tkgrid.configure(bot1,sticky="ew")
```

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn’t use `require` because it silently swallows errors. Use `library` instead.

Comment: Thank you; I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my own question. Here it is.
I have made a frame inside the frame. The inner frame is handled through  tkpack, thus allowing me to resize easily the buttons. However, the outer frame is handled through tkgrid, which allows me to give it a fixed position within the main panel.

```
require(tcltk)

botos1 <- function(panel){panel}
panel01<- tktoplevel(bg="darkcyan")

row1 = tkframe(panel01,width = 500, height = 70, bg = "yellow",borderwidth = 3)

tkgrid(row1,row=0)
tkgrid.configure(row1,sticky="new")
tkgrid.columnconfigure(panel01,0,weight=1)

row11 = tkframe(row1,width = 450, height = 50, bg = "cyan",borderwidth = 3)

bot1<- tkbutton(row11,text="Time series1",width = 35,command=botos1)
bot2 <- tkbutton(row11,text="Time series2",width = 35,command=botos1)
bot3 <- tkbutton(row11,text="Time series3",width = 35,command=botos1)

tkpack(bot1,side="left",expand=TRUE,fill="both")
tkpack(bot2,side="left",expand=TRUE,fill="both")
tkpack(bot3,side="left",expand=TRUE,fill="both")

tkpack(row11,anchor="nw",fill="both")
```